# What's different from using UploadProgress with Lighttpd vs Upload Progress module in Nginx?

Tags: file-upload, nginx

I have an app that successfully tracks upload's progress using UploadProgress & Lighttpd, and I'm porting it over to Nginx.

After reading the documentation: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule I'm not very clear on wether they work the same way or not.

Currently, the process goes like this:

1. I have an HTML page with a form whose action is an iframe on the same page (so the upload doesn't take the visitor out of it).
2. I have the uploadprogress PHP extension installed and also have it installed as a Lighttpd module.
3. Then, once I submit the file, I make AJAX requests to a PHP script of mine that uses uploadprogress_get_info() to get info on the file upload progress, and report it back.

Seems like using Nginx, there's no PHP extension, ¿so how do I get the progress info (bytes total vs bytes sent)? ¿and what process/script or whatever gets to update the progressbar?

A full explanation of how Nginx Upload Progress module works behind the scenes and how all components relate to each other (my html page, my php page where the form is submitted to, nginx, the file, etc)

Thanks!